# How is expl3 typed?

Tags: expl3

In developing an `expl3` add-on package, I want to continue the trends set in the language I'm working in and *not* introduce new patterns.  Can anybody speak for the typing model (if any) that is followed in `expl3`?

Specific things that I'm looking for are:

- [Strong vs. Weak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#.22Strong.22_and_.22weak.22_type_systems)
- [Static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking) vs. [Dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type-checking_and_runtime_type_information) (although such strict categorization may be [dubious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Combining_static_and_dynamic_type-checking))
- Any [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Type_safety_and_memory_safety)?

---

From the comments:

> it is the underlying language concepts by which that 'data type' has a 'type.' What makes a `seq` a `seq`? What's to say it isn't a `clist`, or a `coffin`? What happens in the even of 'mismatched' types, as in the following?
>
> ```
> \seq_new:N       \some_seq
> \seq_push:Nn     \some_seq {some item} 
> \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist \some_seq
> \clist_item:Nn   \some_seq 5
> ```
>
> That kind of thing.

Comment: I should note that I did a small test of it: 
`{ \seq_new:N \some_seq}
{ \seq_push:Nn \some_seq {some item} }
{ \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist \some_seq }
{ \clist_item:Nn \some_seq 5 }`.  It is my understanding that nothing was left in the input stream; more importantly, it compiled without error.

Comment: (groups added for clarity, they aren't actually in there.  I understand that some changes would be made local to the group, so I thought I'd mention that.

Comment: Sorry I could not follow what is "typing model", is it data type ?

Comment: @texenthusiast Not exactly; it is the underlying language concepts by which that 'data type' *has* a 'type'.  What makes a 'seq' a 'seq'? What's to say it isn't a 'clist', or a 'coffin'?  What happens in the even of 'mismatched' types, as in my first example-by-comment? That kind of thing.  I'll put some links into the original post via edit.

Comment: @texenthusiast no worries! The cult of TeX has many followers; I can't forget that the majority of them don't have a CS background. :)

Comment: Doc pointers with [latex3:rss feed](http://latex-project.org/latex3svn.rss):[latex3:svn repo](http://latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/) and [At TUG 2012:by Will Robertson and Frank Mittelbach](http://latex-project.org/papers/latex3-local-global-2012.pdf) and [river-valley.tv video](http://river-valley.tv/latex3-architecture-and-current-work-in-progress/) etc.. are available at http://latex-project.org/papers/, BTW Will is mech engg grad:)

Comment: Initially, a comma separates the items in a `clist` while a `\seq_item:n` separates the items in a `seq`.  So the `\l_tmpa_clist` contains `\seq_item:n {someitem}`, and has no fifth item so `\clist_item:Nn \some_seq 5` returns nothing.  I guess that the "typing" is in the structure of the storage format (?).

Comment: As @ScottH. says, using `clist` functions on something that is not a `clist` is likely to be permissive: all that it 'looks like' is that the list is too short. The same isn't necessarily true of other mismatch combinations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've not got a computer science background, so rather than answer in terms I don't really understand, I'm going to try to answer by describing how things are implemented and what will happen if you misbehave!

TeX is a macro expansion language, and so a lot of storage comes down to 'use a macro'. At the same time, TeX provides us with various forms of register by dedicated purposes, which can be addressed either by number or more commonly by allocated name. The two types of storage have different behaviours at the 'raw' level. With the exception of  toks, the registers are all rather limited in what they accept and so macros or toks are needed to build any other data forms.

Notable, the `expl3` documentation makes no particular statement on how variables at that level are implemented. This is deliberate, as for example the `prop` data type used to be implemented using a register (`toks`) but is currently implemented as a macro 'behind the scenes'.

As a result of the above, exactly what happens if you do the 'wrong' thing depends on the variable in question. The `dim`, `int`, `muskip`, and `skip` variables are all implemented as TeX registers. Thus if you try

```
\dim_set:Nn \l_my_dim { 10 }
\dim_set:Nn \l_my_dim { a }
```

TeX will complain. Due to the way they are implemented, you also get an error with

```
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { foo }
```

while

```
\int_set:Nn \l_undefined_int { 10 }
```

complains about an undefined control sequence.

On the other hand, `tl`, `clist`, `fp`, `prop` and `seq` are implemented (at present) as macros. TeX does no error checking here, so the fact that they are distinct is down to how the `expl3` code tries to manipulate them. Assignment to these data types does not rely on them begin defined (although with checking active some `expl3` code will complain if you try to set an undefined one). Thus

```
\prop_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { foo } { bar }
```

will work fine but you will get into trouble with say

```
\seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
```

as the code implementing `\seq_pop:NN` is designed around certain tokens being left in the input stream.

It's worth noting a couple of things here:

1. We could in principal implement at least `prop` and `seq` as toks, as they don't have to expand without a `\..._use:N` function. The `tl` data type explicitly does expand without an accessor.
2. Bruno has some ideas about making generalised 'objects' which then might lead to `prop` and `seq` starting with some check value which says to `expl3` 'I am a ...'. However, `tl` functions will always be low-level and ignore this, so

   ```
   \tl_set:Nn \<control sequence>
   ```

   is always going to set the control sequence regardless. (A lot of the 'higher level' macro-based functions are behind the scenes either equal to or based on equivalent `tl` ones.)

TeX does some coercion of numerical types in some places. So

```
\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 10 pt }
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \l_tmpa_dim }
\int_show:N \l_tmpa_int
```

gives `655360`, *i.e.* 10 pt expressed in sp!

Coffins are a bit of an odd case as they actually need two underlying items, a box register and a macro (`prop`) to store the handles. At one point the implementation would 'auto-generate' the handles part provided the box existed, and while this isn't currently the case it does have some advantages. As there are various uses of the same information within a coffin, the code does an explicit check that the data structures exist, so unlike other types it's more tricky to abuse coffins. (We avoid getting repeated TeX errors this way.)

As a result of all of the above, the advice of the team is that beyond what we document about data types, 'all bets are off'! The implementation of `expl3` is just macros: it can't change how TeX works, so we rely on conventions.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind is that `expl3` has been designed by a team wanting to use it to solve problems in LaTeX: broadly 'typesetting challenges', which of course take in 'programmatically solving parts of the task'. As such, programming purity is not the priority: we want things to work and not to compromise performance beyond what seems necessary.